# Can Netsparker detect a CVE in an open source library packaged in a WebPack bundle?

Tags: cve

In a recent Netsparker scan, a CVE against an open source JavaScript library was reported (as expected). I'm trying to understand exactly how Netsparker determines: 
 1. Which JS library is being used, and
 2. Which version of the JS library is being used

My guess is that it is parsing the version info from the comments in the header. However, if a JS library is combined with others using WebPack to create a bundle, can Netsparker determine that multiple libraries are being used and detect CVEs for all of them?

I looked on the Netsparker site, but couldn't find enough information. I'm asking this because I don't have a copy of Netsparker that I can arbitrarily run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a support request to Netsparker and they responded with the following:

1. First, they try to retrieve the library name and version number out of the code comments,
2. If that doesn't work, they checks if there is version() (or similar) function.

They mentioned for some libraries the file hash / checksum is used to detect the version.

Also, for multiple libraries that are bundled, they are able to detect the version if code comments are not removed.

See this [link](https://www.netsparker.com/support/fingerprinting-libraries/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of ways to do the check:

1. Parse the version information.
2. Hash the JS file and check it against a known list of software versions.
3. Build a database of pattern checks that identify software and its version.

Option 3 would detect old JS embedded inside a combined file.

I don't know which of these Netsparker actually uses, but you could ask them at [the helpdesk](https://netsparker.zendesk.com/hc/en-us).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I submitted a question and will reply back here when I get an answer.

Comment: Please do! It'd be nice to have a canonical answer.